# Strange behavior of multiprocessing.Pool, why does it grab the wrong function?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I don't understand the behavior of Python's `multiprocessing.Pool` in this situation:

```
import multiprocessing

def f(x): return x
P = multiprocessing.Pool()
def f(x): return x*x

print (P.map(f, range(10)))
print (  map(f, range(10)))
```

which results in the output:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
[0, 1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81]
```

At the point where the print statements are called, isn't there only a single `f`? Why does the Pool grab the first instance of `f`? I would expect that `P.map` and `map` to output the same results!

Comment: It is just as interesting if you move the first `def f(x)` after creating your Pool object.

Comment: i ran the above code in IDLE and it froze my computer

Comment: @Claudiu -- You can't run code with `multiprocessing` from the commandline because `multiprocessing` needs to be able to import `__main__` (which doesn't exist in an interactive interpreter environment).

Comment: @mgilson: well it certainly tried to run and it certainly froze my computer! so what's the correct way of running the above code? i put it in a file `so3.py` and did `python so3.py` and that also seemed to not work

Comment: @Claudiu -- (sorry, in my above comment I said "commandline", but I should have said "interactive interpreter") Putting it into so3.py should have worked (it did for me, that's how I tested this).  What version of python do you have?  What "didn't work?"  (I tested using python 2.7 and python 3.2 on OS-X)

Comment: @mgilson: well it spawned a bunch of processes and it was taking more than 2 seconds so i was afraid of another freeze-up so i CTRL+C'd it at which point it didn't exit out fully forcing me to close the cmd line to kill all the extra processes

Answer (score 3):

This is an excellent question and I hope that someone with more knowledge/experience in Threading (and Multiprocessing) in general can come along and give a better answer, but here's my attempt:

Without really digging into the details here (after a quick look at the source), it appears that the `Pool` constructor spawns multiple threads for handling the queues of tasks.  Those threads seemingly just sit around looking for things to be put into them.  So, it looks like when the thread gets the request to run function `__main__.f`, it does, however, since it's never seen the updated definition of `__main__.f`, it uses the old definition.

Comment: Yup.  Guessing that's why `Pool.map()` is specifically called an asynchronous version of `map`.  It uses the state at time of `Pool` creation.  (I was trying to dig at the source too, but you got it first :))